# Object turned into function in apps script misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have this code in my apps script web app and I would like help understanding it. Basically, the code helps me to load partial views to my web app. In the code below, it helps load render a search view HTML from my backend. Here is the code to start:

```
function loadView(options) {
    var id = typeof options.id === 'undefined' ? "app" : options.id;
    var callback = typeof options.callback === 'undefined' ? function(){} : options.callback
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(html) {
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = html
      typeof options.params === 'undefined' ? callback() : callback(options.params)
    })[options.func]()
  }

  function loadSearchView() {
    loadView({func: 'loadSearchView',
              callback: setDataForSearch})
  }
```

I understand that the loadSearchView() function at the bottom triggers the loadView() function at the top and sends an object. Inside that object there is a key:value pair called:
{
func. 'loadSearchView',
}

As a result, the code then activates another 'loadSearchView() which is a function triggered in the back end of the web app resulting in a search partial HTML.

What I don't understand is this:

1. Why does the loadView() function at the top not follow the pattern of google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().options.func() with **dot notation**; instead it only works when placed in square brackets like this: google.script.run.withSuccessHandler()options.func

2. Secondly, when placed in square brackets how does simply adding () to the end to make itoptions.func activate the backend function, but storing the same function syntax in the options object like below does not work.

```
function loadSearchView() {
    loadView({func: loadSearchView(),
              callback: setDataForSearch})
  }
```

I hope I have made myself clear. Understanding this will help me to move on in my development.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server-side functions are *properties* of the `google.script.run` object. Properties can be accessed using the dot notation when their name is known and hard-coded, but they can also always be accessed by using the bracket notation, giving the name of the property as a text string.

Your code will run the server-side function whose *name* is given by the `object.func` expression that most likely evaluates to a text string that contains the function name. The trailing parentheses `()` make the JavaScript engine run it as a function rather than just returning the property, which in this case would be the function code as a text string.

Comment: That's pretty interesting.  I didn't know that. Thanks